# Howto get yum to install only dependencies for a given pakage?

Tags: yum, rpm, dependencies

I am looking for a way to have yum install only dependencies for a given package, something like an --prepare-for-install option so I can take a snapshot of the prepared system and test the rpm setup with different options or rebuilds of the package itself on a clean system without having to rely on the rpm uninstall and without downloading the dependencies each time.

Comment: You want to _not_ install the package? That doesn't make a whole lot of sense. What are you _really_ trying to do?

Comment: Hi @Michael, the purpose of not installing the package seems clear to me from the text: preparing a system for package testing.

Comment: Right, that's why it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Letting aside the constructiveness of discussing what makes sense to whom, how do you test the rpm you develop then?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This might be really dumb but it should work.

```
PACKAGE=awstats
yum deplist $PACKAGE | grep provider | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq | grep -v $PACKAGE | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' | xargs yum -y install
```

Comment: Works like a charm, who said dumb isn't good :) Would you explain the :a;N;$!ba; part of the sed command for completeness? Thanks

Comment: I honestly don't know, but I pulled it from here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/1252191

Comment: Ok, +1 to him also then

Comment: The `sed` expression joins the multiple lines returned by `yum deplist` and the intervening pipeline, transforming it into a single line of space-separated dependencies.  It's not actually necessary.  You can simplify the above as: `yum deplist $PACKAGE | awk '/provider/ {print $2}' | sort -u | xargs yum -y install`.

Comment: Your solution has an error. Say, if we try to install dependencies for package "mysql" and it has "mysql-common" and "init-mysql" dependencies, we will not see them installed, because they both will be filtered by 'grep -v mysql'.

Comment: I believe [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/220531/26613) addresses @NikitaKipriyanov's point.

Answer (score 4):

```
yum install $(repoquery --requires <package>)
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't account for providers. For instance, I have `git18` which provides `git`; the above command attempts to install `git` as a dependency anyway.

Comment: I believe [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/220531/26613) addresses the valid concern raised by @AaronAdams, above.

Answer (score 0):

Best option I found until now for my packages is to put an "exit 1" into the %pre scriptlet the first time the package is built but I'm looking for cleaner options, not requiring modification of the package itself.